# WinEdt 10.3 meaning of bottom row

Tags: winedt

Please, does anybody know what is it good for the very bottom line of WinEdt 10.3 at least these items are needed:

INS

LINE

--src

[image]

Comment: What happens to `INS` when you press the Insert key?

Comment: Thank you, I now understand. What about the others ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have all details in WinEdt Help:

[image]